# How to write KCL and KVL in these circuits?

Tags: circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws

I want to use KCL on this circuit. I have
\$i-i^{i}_{D2}-i^{i}_{D1}=0\$.

Are the correct currents:

\$i=10V/R_1\$?

\$i^{i}_{D2}=V^{i}_{D2}/R_2\$?

But that is \$i^{i}_{D1}\$? I have no resistor.
[image]

On the circuit below I want to use KVL, but how should I do that? I don't know how to include \$V^{i}_{D1}\$ in KVL.

I guess this is wrong
\$10V-R_1i-V^{i}_{D2}-R_2i^{i}_{D2}-(-10V)+10V=0\$?
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a voltage difference across the resistor R2.

You can Omit \$V^{i}_{D2}\$because \$V^{i}_{D2}\$= 0.

So, voltage across \$R_{2}\$ is =  0V - ( -10V) = 10V.

So, \$i^{i}_{D2} \$= 10V / \$R_{2}\$ = 10V / 5000 Ohms = 2 mA.

As you said: \$i\$ = 10V / \$R_{1}\$ = 1 mA.

You can substitute the values of   \$i^{i}_{D2} \$ and \$i\$ in the equation of KCL to get \$i^{i}_{D1} \$. That's because you don't have a resistor. So, I think this is the easiest way to calculate \$i^{i}_{D1} \$.

\$i^{i}_{D1} \$= \$i\$ - \$i^{i}_{D2} \$= -1 mA. (Negative means opposite direction).

You said \$i^{i}_{D2} \$= \$V^{i}_{D2}\$ / \$R_{2}\$ = 0 !! That's not true. Because \$V^{i}_{D2}\$ is not the voltage across R2. It is the voltage across the diode only (or the switch).

For the second question:

**Edit:** You should choose a smaller loop to include \$V^{i}_{D1}\$ such as:

\$-10V - V^{i}_{D1} + V^{i}_{D2} + i^{i}_{D2}  * R_{2} = 0 \$

Since there's no voltage across points A and B as you demonstrated in the picture, This means: \$  V^{i}_{D2} = 0 \$ and also \$  V^{i}_{D1} = 0 \$.

This makes the equation simpler: \$ -10V + i^{i}_{D2}\$ * \$ R_{2} = 0\$

or \$ i^{i}_{D2} = 10V / R_{2} = 0 \$

For the outer loop: Think of 10V and -10V as a battery of 20V and this battery feeds the two resistors so,

20V = \$i\$ * \$R_{1}\$+ \$i^{i}_{D1} \$ *\$R_{2}\$

Comment: Thank you! What are the equations for the voltage across \$R_2, V_{D1}, V_{D2}\$? (The last two are zero, but I wondering out of curiosity). I don't have any potentials at point A and B (Marked in this picture: https://ibb.co/gBixJv)

Comment: Might be worth modelling on http://everycircuit.com/
(its a free tool and its really visual)

Comment: @JDoeDoe Oh I'm sorry there was a mistake. I've edited my answer. I edited the equation of the smaller loop to include R2, VD1 and VD2.

Answer (score 0):

> Are the correct currents:
>
> \$ i = 10V /  R_1  ?\$

yes.

> \$i^{i}_{D2}=V^{i}_{D2}/R_2 ?\$

No. \$i^{i}_{D2}= 10V / R_2.\$

As \$i = i^{i}_{D1}+ i^{i}_{D2}.\$ solving for \$i^{i}_{D1}\$ is easy.